# Lambda / List Comprehension for addition

Tags: python, lambda, addition, list-comprehension

I am working on a personal project -- a simple, basic calculator in python. I managed to get it mostly up and running, but I have a little more work to do. I'm working on separating functions so I can call them properly in programming sense... Right now, I would like to simplify addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division it using either lambda or list comprehension.

Here is what I'm trying to do...

```
def add(self):
        nsum = 0.0

        print ("This is addition\n\n")
            #Using FOR loop, requests the quantity_of_numbers value of numbers to perform addition

        nsum += x for x in self.nVar1

        self.print_answer(nSum)

        #Resets the variables
        self.nVar1 = []
        nsum = 0.0

        return 0
```

I keep getting error messages like

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'generator'
    logout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this using lambda and list comprehension, what you want is `reduce`.

```
nsum += reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, self.nVar1)
```

As others have noted, python has a built-in `sum` function, which I think is not in fact implemented this way, but is a wrapper for a c function.

For some reason, reduce was removed from the language proper in Python 3.  It is still available if you `import functools`.

Comment: Note that `reduce` is no longer a keyword in Python 3.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to use up as few lines as possible for my program if I am able to like maybe using list comprehension, or lambda. I didn't mean I wanted to use both. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually, reduce isn't exactly list-comprehension, so this doesn't really use both.

Answer (score 2):

This exception:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'generator'
```

is complaining about this:

```
nsum += x for x in self.nVar1
```

where you are trying to add a float (`nsum`) and a generator (`x for x in self.nVar1`)

You could try this:

```
nsum += sum(self.nVar1)
```

where the `sum` function reduces the sequence `self.nVar1` to one number by adding them together and giving you the result.

Comment: What if I want to do something like multiplication, subtraction, or division?

I'm aware that I can use a for loop, but I would like to try to keep it in one line if possible.

Comment: And... Why can't I have the string or tuple printed out when I use a generator? I thought we could do that. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: You can use `reduce` to combine a sequence using a binary operation (though subtraction and division are not associative operations, so you'll have to be more specific about what you want to do). In answer to your other question, if you want to print the contents of a generator, you can convert it to a tuple or a list with tuple(...) or list(...).

Comment: The numbers are stored in a tuple...

for x in range(self.quantity):
            cnbr = float(input("Please enter value #" + str(x+1) + ": "))
            self.nVar1.append(float(cnbr))

Comment: So what specifically is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through the tuple to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, depending on which function is called. Each function will have either nProd *= something, nQuot /= something, nSum += something, or nSub -= something, where "something" is done by either list comprehension or lambda function, or something that makes it simple to do in one line.

Comment: OK. That is what you are trying to do. So what _specifically_ is your question?

Comment: I am basically giving up on this and going to go with the standard for loop. But thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This `x for x in self.nVar1` is a generator expression - it returns a generator, which you try to add to `nsum`, resulting in error.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve the correct solution might be using python's [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) builtin

```
nsum = sum(self.nVar1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of for loop is incorrect that's why you are getting that error message.

Comment: Syntax of for loop for python is for x in range (argu1,argu2,argu3): This is the valid syntax of for loop. In the third argument you have to add increment by whatever integer you want to add.